# Laravel "Method [index] does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name  | Action                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       |       | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index              | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | /                       |       | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@newsSubmit         | web          |
|        | POST     | announcement/get/fields |       | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@newsGetFields      | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                |       | Closure                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   | login | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@login              | web          |
|        | POST     | login/user              |       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@loginUser          | web          |
|        | POST     | notifications/get       |       | App\Http\Controllers\notificationsController@getNotif  | web          |
|        | POST     | notifications/read      |       | App\Http\Controllers\notificationsController@readNotif | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | notifications/view      |       | App\Http\Controllers\notificationsController@index     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@register           | web          |
|        | POST     | register/user           |       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@registerUser       | web          |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Those are all my routes:

```
   //notifications

Route::post('/notifications/get', 'notificationsController@getNotif');
Route::post('/notifications/read', 'notificationsController@readNotif');
Route::get('/notifications/view', 'notificationsController@index');
```

And this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\notifications;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class notificationsController extends Controller
{
    
    public function getNotif(Request $request)
    {

        $id = $request->input('id');

        $notifResult = notifications::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('userID', '=', $id)->where('readed', '=', 0)->get();

        $data = array(
            'notifResult' => $notifResult,
            'notifNumber' => count($notifResult)
        );

        return $data;
    }

    public function readNotif(Request $request)
    {

        $notifid = $request->input('id');

        $findNotif = notifications::findOrFail($notifid);

        $findNotif->readed = 1;

        $findNotif->save();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        return view('notifications');
    }

}
```

Only the index one is not working.

I am trying to display all the notifications when clicking on "View all", View all would take the user to /notifications/view which works but when I get there, I get the `"Method [index] does not exist."` error, and that is, I assume `public function index()`.

### SOLVED

I forgot to save the file....

Comment: Is the filename of your controller `notificationsController.php` or `NotificationsController.php`? Is sometimes has issues when the filename was different then the class name.

Comment: it is notificationsController.php

Answer (score -1):

Tried to clear your view and simple cache. It could be due to cache.

Comment: That should be added as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I am testing on localhost, does it do cache?

Comment: @Merky yes it will do cache

Comment: it doesn't happen due to cache, tried on more browsers